# Laravel Find String in Array Within Collection

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to find a string in my User model, however, the field that I'm looking in is an array.

For example, I have a collection of users and each User record has a column called "attributes". The record in this column is an array of stats (i.e. A, B, C). I am trying to search by stat and find all users with that stat, but I'm having trouble determining the "haystack" since it's within a collection already.

Logically, I think of `$users = User::where('attributes', $stat)->get();`

That returns nothing...TIA.

Comment: Have you tried using it this way?
$users = User::whereRaw("JSON_CONTAINS(attributes, '[$stat]' )")->get();

Comment: Which way? The line I have in the post is how I have tried it...I'm trying to see if the filter() method will work.

Comment: What database are you using? What kind of field are you using to save the items?

Comment: try $users = User::where('attributes', 'like', "%{$stat}%")->get();

Comment: I am using a TEXT field just due to the possible size of the entry. The data is supplied by a multi select element from the blade template.

Comment: Have you tried like making separate table 'attributes' and using eloquent relationship to associate the user with attributes.

Comment: Actually, I did just do that. Now need to figure out how to query the relationship.